# Java - make boolean isHigherGeneration () metod return YES/NO

Tags: java, methods, return, boolean

I am having a little trouble with my homework.
 I have to have a boolean isHigherGeneration() method that compares 2 CPU objects based on their generation. 
I was able to make my code compare the 2 objects, but I need the result to return YES/NO instead of true/false. 
I tried creating a string and transforming it into a boolean, but it didn't work. Can someone help me please? 
Here is my code:

```
public boolean isHigherGeneration(CPU cpu){
        String YES = "YES";
        String NO = "NO";
        boolean t = Boolean.valueOf(YES);
        boolean n = Boolean.valueOf(NO);

        if (this.generation > cpu.generation)
            return t ;
        else
            return n;
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: It is worth pointing out that `Boolean.valueOf(YES)` is `Boolean.FALSE`, and `Boolean.valueOf(NO)` is `Boolean.FALSE` too. The only string which gives you `Boolean.TRUE` is `"true"` (or some other string equal to that, ignoring case). (And you may as well use `Boolean.parseBoolean(String)` instead, since you immediately unbox the result of `valueOf`).

Comment: please check the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds from the question like it doesn't want you to return a `boolean`, but a `String` with either the value `YES` or the value `NO` instead of a `boolean`, so what you need to do is translate the result of the `boolean` expression into a `String` with the value `YES` or the value `NO`.

Thus, in this case, there's no need to play around with `boolean` in your code. You can compare the `CPU` generation and just return `YES` if the value is `true` and `NO` if the value is `false`:

```
public String isHigherGeneration(CPU cpu) {
    if (generation > cpu.generation) {
        return "YES";
    } else {
        return "NO";
    }
}
```

Edit: From the sounds of the requirements, you need a `boolean` method that returns `String`, which is impossible. (That's like saying you want to buy an apple but end up with a pear.) If you do need a `String` result and a `boolean` method, you could divide them into three like this:

```
// Boolean method
public boolean isHigherGeneration(CPU cpu) {
    return generation > cpu.generation;
}
```

```
// String method
public String toYesNo(boolean result) {
    if (result) {
        return "YES";
    } else {
        return "NO";
    }
}
```

```
// Converter
public String isHigherGenerationYesNo(CPU cpu) {
    return toYesNo(isHigherGeneration(cpu));
}
```

but this just all seems silly. I think maybe we're having a misunderstanding in the question. Could you post the question verbatim so that we can ensure that we've understood it correctly?

Comment: So what you are telling me is that I shouldn't use a boolean isHigherGeneration() method? Right? Because if it is, the problem is that I have to use a boolean method (I will lose points if I don't use a boolean method), I know it works if a do String.

Comment: I reread your question and noticed the requirement that you use a boolean method. The question itself doesn't really make sense: it requires a `boolean` method but wants you to return `String`?

The only way to do this would be to divide it up into two methods. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I know it seem weird what I was asked to do in the homework and I completely agree with you that it doesn't make sence.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return "YES" or "NO", the return type of the method must be a `String`:

```
public String isHigherGeneration(CPU cpu) {
    if (this.generation > cpu.generation)
        return "YES";
    else
        return "NO";
}
```

or

```
public String isHigherGeneration(CPU cpu) {
    return this.generation > cpu.generation ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```

Comment: But logically, I wouldn't be using a boolean is HigherGeneration() method, right? In my homework, I have to use a boolean method

Comment: @Jennifer if you have to return "YES" or "NO", you cannot return a boolean.